# USB stick made with UNetbootin missing BOOTMGR.

Tags: usb, unetbootin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu not booting from USB on laptop (no optical drive)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161328/ubuntu-not-booting-from-usb-on-laptop-no-optical-drive)

I downloaded 12.04 32-bit ISO and am trying to make a USB stick with it for me to boot from and install on my HD. I followed the instructions in UNetbootin but my USB stick is missing its `bootmgr` so it won't boot.

Any advice? I don't have a CD-burner nor a CD-ROM on my laptop which I am trying to install on.

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using some linux distro to make the live USB, you can use the commands given in the following link:

[How to make an Ubuntu live USB stick in Fedora?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17251/how-to-make-an-ubuntu-live-usb-stick-in-fedora/177704#177704)

If you're using Windows, you can try any other Live USB creating software such as [YUMI (Your Universal Multiboot Installer)](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) or [LinuxLive USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/).

Comment: I found out that it possibly might have been an issue with the USB stick being formatted in NTFS :) Formatted in FAT32 and it worked perfectly!