# How to replace Mint with Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, mint

I've got Linux Mint 17.1 on my laptop installed by someone else and I want to replace Mint with Ubuntu. I don't have a Windows system on it - just Mint.

Can anyone tell me - in newbie friendly terms - how to do that?

When I type `df -h` in terminal, the result is as below:

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1  684G 189G 460G 30% / 
none       4.0K 0    4.0K 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev       1.9G 4.0K 1.9G 1% /dev
tmpfs      386M 1.4M 385M 1% /run
none       5.0M 0    5.0M 0% /run/lock
none       1.9G 32M  1.9G 2% /run/shm
none       100M 28K  100M 1% /run/user
```

Comment: "Ubunto"? Have a look :) http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15684/ubuntu-misspellings

Comment: Do have data stored on your computer which you don't have in a cloud service anyway and want to keep? Do you use a home partition? If you're not sure about the second one, just post the output of `df -h`.

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       684G  189G  460G  30% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           386M  1.4M  385M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G   32M  1.9G   2% /run/shm
none            100M   28K  100M   1% /run/user
 It was the answer of second question. And about first question my answer is no. I stored all my data in a hard disk

Comment: Some one else has installed mint on my system. please help me instead of this kinds of answers

Comment: Providing that you have a backup of your data you should be able to follow all the guidance on the ubuntu site. By backup I mean separate from the single hard drive /dev/sda. Folks make comments rather than providing an answer to aid both you and them. This site requires a "complete" answer which in your case is pretty difficult with the limited information provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have a home partition and don't seem experienced, just copy all your personal files to an external HDD.

Meanwhile, download Ubuntu. You can just [click this link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso) and [create a live USB stick with it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17251/how-to-make-an-ubuntu-live-usb-stick-in-fedora).

Boot up Ubuntu from the USB stick, click on "Install Ubuntu". Connect to the internet (you don't need to do anything if you're connected via lan but have to choose the wifi network and enter the password if you want to connect via wifi and Ubuntu doesn't read this information from your Fedora installation automatically), check on the boxes which offer you to download stuff during the installation, and then choose "Erase everything and install Ubuntu". There isn't much more to do after that and it's really easy.

After the installation completed, you'll be asked to reboot. Do that, remove your USB stick, and copy your files back once the installed system booted up.