# BIOS doesn't find UBuntu iso after Fedora installation

Tags: bios

Created a bootable USB from an iso-file with

```
sudo dd if=./ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sda1 bs=8M
```

using
[How to make an Ubuntu live USB stick in Fedora?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17251/how-to-make-an-ubuntu-live-usb-stick-in-fedora)
BIOS does not see this USB. Did Fedora 31 mess up my BIOS and what can I do?

Comment: This seems to be a Fedora issue and not Ubuntu perhaps they can explain whatever it might have changed in your BIOS!

Comment: You copied ISO to partition, not to drive. System cannot boot from a partition. Use sda, not sda1. Note that this will totally erase drive as  DVD type data is in partition area of MBR. You have to use dd to clear first sector to be able to use sda  flash drive again.